# jQuery plugin instances variable with event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am writing my first jQuery plugin which is a tree browser. It shall first show the top level elements and on click go deeper and show (depending on level) the children in a different way.

I got this up and running already. But now I want to implement a "back" functionality and for this I need to store an array of clicked elements for each instance of the tree browser (if multiple are on the page).

I know that I can put instance private variables with "this." in the plugin.

But if I assign an event handler of the onClick on a topic, how do I get this instance private variable? $(this) is referencing the clicked element at this moment.

Could please anyone give me an advise or a link to a tutorial how to get this done?

I only found tutorial for instance specific variables without event handlers involved.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I cleaned out the huge code generation and kept the logical structure. This is my code:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.myTreeBrowser = function (options) {

    clickedElements = [];

    var defaults = {
        textColor: "#000",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        fontSize: "1em",
        titleAttribute: "Title",
        idAttribute: "Id",
        parentIdAttribute: "ParentId",
        levelAttribute: "Level",
        treeData: {}
    };

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.myTreeBrowser.defaults, options);


    function getTreeData(id) {
        if (opts.data) {
            $.ajax(opts.data, { async: false, data: { Id: id } }).success(function (resultdata) {
                opts.treeData = resultdata;
            });
        }
    }

    function onClick() {

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        var parentContainer = getParentContainer($(this));

        handleOnClick(parentContainer, id);
    }

    function handleOnClick(parentContainer, id) {
        if (opts.onTopicClicked) {
            opts.onTopicClicked(id);
        }

       clickedElements.push(id);

        if (id) {

            var clickedElement = $.grep(opts.treeData, function (n, i) { return n[opts.idAttribute] === id })[0];

            switch (clickedElement[opts.levelAttribute]) {
                case 1:
                    renderLevel2(parentContainer, clickedElement);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    renderLevel3(parentContainer, clickedElement);
                    break;
                default:
                    debug('invalid level element clicked');
            }
        } else {
            renderTopLevel(parentContainer);
        }
    }

    function getParentContainer(elem) {
        return $(elem).parents('div.myBrowserContainer').parents()[0];
    }

    function onBackButtonClick() {
        clickedElements.pop(); // remove actual element to get the one before
        var lastClickedId = clickedElements.pop();

        var parentContainer = getParentContainer($(this));
        handleOnClick(parentContainer, lastClickedId);
    }



    function renderLevel2(parentContainer, selectedElement) {
        $(parentContainer).html('');

        var browsercontainer = $('<div>').addClass('myBrowserContainer').appendTo(parentContainer);

        //... rendering the div ...
        // for example like this with a onClick handler
        var div = $('<div>').attr('data-id', element[opts.idAttribute]).addClass('fct-bs-col-md-4 pexSubtopic').on('click', onClick).appendTo(subtopicList);

        // ... rendering the tree

        var backButton = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-default').text('Back').appendTo(browsercontainer);
        backButton.on('click', onBackButtonClick);

    }


    function renderLevel3(parentContainer, selectedElement) {
        $(parentContainer).html('');

        var browsercontainer = $('<div>').addClass('myBrowserContainer').appendTo(parentContainer);

        //... rendering the div ...
        // for example like this with a onClick handler
        var div = $('<div>').attr('data-id', element[opts.idAttribute]).addClass('fct-bs-col-md-4 pexSubtopic').on('click', onClick).appendTo(subtopicList);

        // ... rendering the tree

        var backButton = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-default').text('Back').appendTo(browsercontainer);
        backButton.on('click', onBackButtonClick);

    }


    function renderTopLevel(parentContainer) {

        parentContainer.html('');

        var browsercontainer = $('<div>').addClass('fct-page-pa fct-bs-container-fluid pexPAs myBrowserContainer').appendTo(parentContainer);

        // rendering the top level display

    }



    getTreeData();

    //top level rendering! Lower levels are rendered in event handlers.
    $(this).each(function () {
        renderTopLevel($(this));
    });

    return this;
};



// Private function for debugging.
function debug(debugText) {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log(debugText);
    }
};
```

}(jQuery));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use one more class variable and pass `this` to it. Usually I call it `self`. So `var self = this;` in constructor of your plugin Class and you are good to go.

Object oriented way:

```
function YourPlugin(){
    var self = this;
}

YourPlugin.prototype = {
    constructor: YourPlugin,

    clickHandler: function(){
         // here the self works
    }
}
```

[Check this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1w4whj2j/)

Or simple way of passing data to eventHandler:

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", {
  self: this
}, function( event ) {
  alert( event.data.self);
});
```

Comment: And how to get this "self" from the eventHandler? my event handler looks like this:         function onClick() {

            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

            var parentContainer = getParentContainer($(this));

            handleOnClick(parentContainer, id);
        }

Comment: You should post more of your code when you want specific answer. If you are using only functional programming approach this is not doable because eventHandler is executed in global context. If your plugin is a class with instances and eventHandler is its method, then you have access to instance variables.

Comment: I updated my question. Is there a good tutorial out in the web where I could dig deeper in how to do it the right way?

Comment: I updated answer and added Fiddle to point you the way. Open console and click button. You will see that 'self' is pointing to YourPlugin object, while this points still to object that click was invoked on.

As for tutorial MDN is always a good start https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: I could now change my plugin to use this clean approach. Thank you yery much. That did help me a lot. :-)

Comment: glad I helped :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery proxy function:

```
$(yourElement).bind("click", $.proxy(this.yourFunction, this));
```

You can then use `this` in `yourFunction` as the `this` in your plugin.